# XRAY shutdown in sidecar container in ECS fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I'm trying to make XRAY work as a sidecar container on ECS fargate.

However, it is shutting down and stopping the task.

These are the logs:

```
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Shutdown Initiated. Current epoch in nanoseconds: 1619452799073953600
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Info] Got shutdown signal: terminated
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] telemetry: done!
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Segment batch: done!
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Segment batch: done!
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Segment batch: done!
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Segment batch: done!
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Segment batch: done!
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Segment batch: done!
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Segment batch: done!
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Segment batch: done!
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] processor: done!
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Trace segment: received: 0, truncated: 0, processed: 0
2021-04-26 08:59:592021-04-26T15:59:59Z [Debug] Shutdown finished. Current epoch in nanoseconds: 1619452799074286437
2021-04-26 08:59:582021-04-26T15:59:58Z [Info] Starting proxy http server on 0.0.0.0:2000
2021-04-26 08:59:582021-04-26T15:59:58Z [Error] Get instance id metadata failed: RequestError: send request failed
2021-04-26 08:59:58caused by: Get http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id: dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: invalid argument
2021-04-26 08:59:582021-04-26T15:59:58Z [Debug] Using Endpoint: https://xray.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2021-04-26 08:59:582021-04-26T15:59:58Z [Debug] Telemetry initiated
2021-04-26 08:59:582021-04-26T15:59:58Z [Info] HTTP Proxy server using X-Ray Endpoint : https://xray.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2021-04-26 08:59:582021-04-26T15:59:58Z [Debug] Using Endpoint: https://xray.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2021-04-26 08:59:582021-04-26T15:59:58Z [Debug] Batch size: 50
2021-04-26 08:59:572021-04-26T15:59:57Z [Debug] Get hostname metadata failed: RequestError: send request failed
2021-04-26 08:59:57caused by: Get http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname: dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: invalid argument
2021-04-26 08:59:572021-04-26T15:59:57Z [Debug] Using proxy address:
2021-04-26 08:59:572021-04-26T15:59:57Z [Debug] Fetch region us-east-1 from environment variables
2021-04-26 08:59:572021-04-26T15:59:57Z [Info] Using region: us-east-1
2021-04-26 08:59:572021-04-26T15:59:57Z [Debug] ARN of the AWS resource running the daemon:
2021-04-26 08:59:572021-04-26T15:59:57Z [Info] Initializing AWS X-Ray daemon 3.2.0
2021-04-26 08:59:572021-04-26T15:59:57Z [Debug] Listening on UDP 0.0.0.0:2000
2021-04-26 08:59:572021-04-26T15:59:57Z [Info] Using buffer memory limit of 37 MB
2021-04-26 08:59:572021-04-26T15:59:57Z [Info] 592 segment buffers allocated
```

I found this and checked I have everything I needed: https://github.com/aws/aws-app-mesh-examples/blob/db4a8d49ab61c62dbc254cd4d35a3911df4cc32c/walkthroughs/howto-alb/app.yaml#L61, particularly for the TASK role (and permissions).

I don't understand what's going on and googling doesn't provide good hints neither.

I will appreciate help.
Thanks

Comment: I might be totally wrong here, but any chance you're seeing your task being shut down/restarted on the ECS/Fargate console multiple times under the Events tab?